# Behaviour of back button on ajax and non-ajax page with the same url

Tags: ajax, caching, back

I have got two versions of content (ajax and non-ajax) at one url. One version is with renderred layout for non-ajax requests and the second ajax-version is just the content itself without the layout. The problem is that browsers (chrome/firefox) seems not to differentiate between ajax/non-ajax requests when fetching pages from cache If I click on back button. There are situations where I load the non-ajax version then I do some browsing and then when I return back (by clicking back button repeatedly) I get the ajax ("unformatted") version because that is the version stored currently in the cache. Is this a known issue? Do I need to differentiate ajax vs non-ajax requests in urls e.g. by `?ajax=1`?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ajax function to not cache the call. That way when a user hits back, it will render the page layout. If you are using jquery it would look something like this:

```
$.ajax
  type: "GET"
  dataType: "json"
  cache: false
  url: self.url
  success: (data) ->
    #do something
```